# AppIntroSlider with Components

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to create an appintroslider in react-native with a list of components. When I execute it does not show me anything. Am I creating the list of components well?

An example without the list of components, if not with a list of normal objects works normally.

Thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
import Main from './Component/Main';
import Picture from './Component/Picture';
import CurrentWeather from './Component/CurrentWeather';

const slides = [
  {
    key: '1',
    component: <Main />,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    component: <Picture />,
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    component: <CurrentWeather />,
  },
];
const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const on_Done_all_slides = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  const on_Skip_slides = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  if (show) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Welcome </Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppIntroSlider
        slides={slides}
        onDone={on_Done_all_slides}
        showSkipButton={true}
        onSkip={on_Skip_slides}
      />
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: component is not a slide object

Comment: you can't use your components in appIntroSlider

Comment: Is true. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
import Main from './Component/Main';
import Picture from './Component/Picture';
import CurrentWeather from './Component/CurrentWeather';

const slides = [
  {
    key: '1',
    component: <Main />,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    component: <Picture />,
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    component: <CurrentWeather />,
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const on_Done_all_slides = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  const on_Skip_slides = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  const renderItems = item => {
    return item.component;
  }

  if (show) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Welcome </Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppIntroSlider
        renderItem={renderItems}
        slides={slides}
        onDone={on_Done_all_slides}
        showSkipButton={true}
        onSkip={on_Skip_slides}
      />
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

component is not a AppIntroSlider slide object.